# Two dimensional (position) time series prediction in Keras using LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to use the Keras LSTM implementation to predict a series of x, y pairs into the future. The x, y pairs specify location in a 2D plane. I would like to predict them 60 steps into the future.

I have 36k data pairs, which I have split up into 30k for training and 5880k for testing. I have prepared the training data by creating a 3D array of shape (30000, 60, 2) where each element is a rolling 60 length snippet of the training data, e.g. [[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], ... [x59, y59]], [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... [x60, y60]], ... [x30000, y30000], [x30001, y30001], ... [x30059, y30059]]]. The target data is the exact same thing, only offset by 60 elements. The idea is to basically use 60 pairs to predict the next 60 pairs.

I'm getting the following error, indicating that the model is expecting the target data to have only two dimensions.

ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected lstm_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30000, 60, 2)

It looks like the model is dropping the fact that my data is 2D. Clearly I am missing something conceptually here, but I'm not sure what it is. I'd be grateful if someone could put me on the right track.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Activation, GRU, Dropout

TRAINING_SET_SIZE = 30000
epochs = 1

original_data = genfromtxt('training_data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='int')

training_set = []
for i in range(len(original_data) - 120):
    training_set.append(original_data[i:i+120])
training_set = np.array(training_set)

train_input = []
train_output = []
for i in range(TRAINING_SET_SIZE):
    train_input.append(training_set[i][0:60])
    train_output.append(training_set[i][60:120])

train_input = np.array(train_input)
train_output = np.array(train_output)

test_input = []
test_output = []
for i in range(TRAINING_SET_SIZE, len(original_data) - 120):
    test_input.append(training_set[i][0:60])
    test_output.append(training_set[i][60:120])

test_input = np.array(test_input)
test_output = np.array(test_output)

s = (train_input.shape[1], train_input.shape[2])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(60, input_shape=s, unroll=True))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.summary()
print("Inputs: {}".format(model.input_shape))
print("Outputs: {}".format(model.output_shape))
print("Actual input: {}".format(train_input.shape))
print("Actual output: {}".format(train_output.shape))

print('Training')
model.fit(train_input, train_output, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=1, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, shuffle=False)

model.save('my_model.h5')

score = model.evaluate(test_input, test_output, batch_size=1)
print(score)

print('Predicting')
predicted_output = model.predict(test_input, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: first you need to have an output layer in you network the size of your output data `model.add(Dense(2))` after your LSTM layer

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I did that, but I'm still getting the same error, only this time from the Dense layer. I'm hoping for an output shape of (60, 2), i.e. 60 samples of 2 dimensions. The shape of my train_output is (30000, 60, 2)

Comment: also add `return_sequences=True` to your LSTM layer

Comment: Thanks again! That actually made it run. I'm getting a predicted_output of size (5880, 60, 2), which makes sense. However, every single element is 1.0. Any ideas on why that would be?

Comment: Are you normalizing you input data? I don't see that anywhere. Also for regression your activation on the output layer should be linear

Comment: Sure appreciate your help. I'm not normalizing the data. It's all x, y coordinate pairs with x in the range of (50, 650) and y about (50, 350). Should I normalize the coordinates somehow? I tried a linear activation function. Now the predicted output looks pretty much like coordinates, but there's still something weird. Each of the 5880 output sequences of (60, 2) is identical. And within each sequence, the coordinates settle into a steady state after about 4 pairs. It's like the coordinates are converging, i.e. the model is predicting that the thing just slows down and stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149258/discussion-between-djk47463-and-john-marion).